# How to set a currency as active when installing a module in odoo?

Tags: python, odoo

I have a module where I need to use Dominican Pesos (DOP) and Dollars (USD) as currencies, but DOP is not active by Default. How can I set DOP as active when installing a module? 
I have try with this but that code is for adding a new currency, and what I want to do is to set the field 'active' of an existing currency as True.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<odoo>
  <data noupdate="1">
    <record id="74" model="res.currency">
      <field name="active">True</field>
    </record>
  </data>
</odoo>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the external id used in the `base` module.

```
<record id="base.DOP" model="res.currency">
    <field name="active" eval="True"/>
</record>
```

Comment: Sorry, but is not working, even whem I check in the postgres database the active attribute is set to FALSE

Comment: Are you sure the data file is loaded?

Comment: Thank you so much, I had to unstall the module and install it again

Comment: I am glad to help you